# Geometric proof of dot product distributive property

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-construction

I'm working my way through a text book for fun in order to keep my math brain fresh and came across this simple yet perplexing problem.

"Demonstrate geometrically that the dot product is distributive"

I can do this algebraically but what would a geometric proof of this look like?

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice picture of this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Scalar_projection_and_first_properties) (though you should really imagine this picture as $3$D).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

$$a \cdot (b+c) = a \cdot b + a \cdot c$$

"The 'projection' of $a$ onto $b+c$ is the same as the sums of the 'projections' of $a$ onto $b$ and of $a$ onto $c$." (You'll have to draw the triangle formed by $b$, $c$, and $b+c$. Also, you will need to be precise about what the 'projection' is.)